# ASP.net claims user not authenticate when calling from API

Tags: asp.net, identity, claims-based-identity, claims

In asp.net project when putting the below piece of code in an api get method and calling this method through the browser as a link I am getting the claims of authenticated user, while when calling this api from another asp.net project I am getting that the user is not authenticated.
So how can I call this api method from the other project as if I am opening it from the same browser and get the user as authenticated?

```
           IEnumerable<Claim> claims = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).Claims;

            bool isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            Claim claimName = claims.FirstOrDefault(c =>
                c.Type.Contains("nonqualified")
                || string.Equals(c.Type, "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue , by reading the cookie of ASP.NET_SessionId and .AspNet.Cookies from browser and sending them with the api request